# Pandas group and record grouped values

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataset:

```
Code    Value
100004  1
1017    1
1017    3
1071    1
1071    3
3039    1
3397    1
3397    3
```

I was able to count the Value using pandasDataFrame.groupby('Code', as_index=False).agg('count')

I would like to count and in the same time to record the values in a new column. I want the result to look like the example bellow

```
Code       NoValues      Values
100004     1             1
1017       2             1,3
1071       2             1,3
3039       1             1
3397       2             1,3
```

Is it possible to do it with pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `groupby` + `agg`:

```
df.Value.groupby(df.Code).agg({'Values': lambda g: list(g), 'NumValues': lambda g: len(g)}).reset_index()
```

For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Code': [1004, 1004, 1007], 'Value': [1, 2, 8]})
>>> df.Value.groupby(df.Code).agg({'Values': lambda g: list(g), 'NumValues': lambda g: len(g)}).reset_index()
    Code    NumValues   Values
0   1004    2   [1, 2]
1   1007    1   [3]
```

Comment: Thank you @Ami Tavory, but is not what I am looking for. In the column Values I want to record as string separated by comma which are the values that were counted. So, for code 1004 I have a count of 2 and is formed by 1 and 2, so the final result is 1004 2(number of values) 1,2 (values that were counted)

Comment: @IonutSandric Not, that's OK - I see that now. It's just that I first answered, then formatted your question. Hold on a sec.

Comment: @IonutSandric See now.

Comment: Is it possible to have just one row for each code? 1004 2 (number of time the code appears in the list) and [1,2] the values that were counted?

Comment: @IonutSandric Oh, and please format your questions better in the future - it would allow seeing what you meant to begin with.

Comment: Thank you @Ami Tavory very much! I am new to pandas and stack overflow, I'll try to be more concise next time

Comment: @IonutSandric No problem, and you're welcome. All the best.